# Running 16:9 games on a 4:3 screen device

Tags: applications, screen-resolution

I recently bought a tablet with a 4:3 screen. I noticed that some games don't seem to take this into account and the graphics end up stretched vertically. It can be rather distracting at times.

Is there a way to fix this, e.g. letterboxing to preserve the original aspect ratio?

Comment: One work-around is reporting the issues to the resp. devs, so they fix them up :)